# Using numeric position to order sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm fairly new to SQL and was wondering what relationship order by has to columns from a SQL logic perspective.

For Example,

If I have

```
SELECT NAME, sal, comm, id
FROM Cust c, Account a
WHERE c.acc_num = a.acc_num
    AND comm > ALL (
        SELECT Avg(sa.comm)
        FROM savings sa
        GROUP BY sa.total
        )
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

Will the statement actually return an ordering of sal and comm respectively or would this error out?

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle? Sql Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: Yes, it would. The numbers used on a order by statement as you did means the position of the fields on the select statement. For your case 2=sal and 3=comm

Comment: @Cameron I'm using Oracle...

Comment: @JorgeCampos when I try running the query I'm getting an error. Is this because the `GROUP BY` statement should be referred to in the SELECT statement?

Comment: Your error is because you are trying to group a column not specified in the select statement here `SELECT Avg(sa.comm)` it should be `SELECT sa.total,  Avg(sa.comm)` or you take out the group by since you are getting only the average it is not needed at all

Comment: That make sense! Thanks @JorgeCampos!

Answer (score 0):

You need `SELECT sa.total, Avg(sa.comm)` but then `AND comm > ALL` wouldnt work

Also even when `ORDER BY 2, 3` works is better use the real names to avoid break if someone change the order of the columns, also improve reading.

```
SELECT NAME, sal, comm, id
FROM Cust c, Account a
WHERE c.acc_num = a.acc_num
    AND comm > ALL (
        SELECT sa.total, Avg(sa.comm)
        FROM savings sa
        GROUP BY sa.total
        )
ORDER BY sal, comm
```